# Cannot disable "react/prop-types" in my eslintrc file in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

Uh, I've installed eslint for my React app and it's giving me nothing but problems. Every time I open up a file and edit it, it breaks my app with the following errors:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/Dashboard/Dashboard.js
  Line 17:22:  'history' is missing in props validation                    react/prop-types
...
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I don't want to go back and update my 50+ component/files with propTypes, so I've tried disabling the prop-types in my .eslintrc.json file with `"react/prop-types": "off"` I've also tried replacing `"off"` with `0`, to no avail.

According to various Q/A's on Stack, this should work, but for some reason it's having no effect for me. Can someone help me get my app working again please?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out everything was working correctly. What I needed to to was to open and save the file that was causing problems, as it seems eslint was using an old version of the file while I still had it open? Unsure, but it's fixed now.